# Git commit not Syncing with Github

Tags: git, github

I am trying to commit a new file on git.

i created a new file in my Repo using below:
touch help.txt
git add help.txt
git commit 
git push

> But it did not reflect in the github repo while the file is there in local repo.

Comment: You have to add a bit more detail.  What was the output of `git push`?  Can you confirm via `git show` that the file got committed?

Comment: Hi jcm,I got the below output:To https://github.com/Puneet1/MyProject1                                      ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)                     error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Puneet1/MyProject1'   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.             hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.                                  hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: git show gives:                                                                           diff --git a/readme.txt b/readme.txt            index e69de29..764a3dc 100644                   --- a/readme.txt                                +++ b/readme.txt                                @@ -0,0 +1 @@                                   +Hello Puneet                                   \ No newline at end of file

Comment: Why is the help.txt file not showing on Github ? Any one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason and solution are in the output of `git push`.

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull
>   ...') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git
>   push --help' for details.

Your changes were rejected by the remote because it has changes that your local branch does not.
You can do

`git pull --rebase origin name-of-branch-you-want-to-push-to
git push origin name-of-branch-you-want-to-push-to`

Comment: Do i need to be online and logged into my Git hub account while performing this operation. I am new to Git and GitHub and it's a learning curve for me.

Comment: I tried Git fetch and then git rebase and go the response "There is no tracking information for the current branch"

Comment: You'll need to be connected to the Internet but you won't need to be logged into GitHub.

Comment: I am both, But still i see the help.txt exists in the local but not in the Github. I am really sorry for so much bother but i think i am missing something obvious.The commands i typed were as listed in my original question.

Comment: Check the updated answer.  Being new to technology is not a bother, everyone starts somewhere.  What Git books/tutorials have you tried?  I like this one: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: I tried this beautifully written blog on readwrite: http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1 and went through both parts

Comment: What path should i give in place pf feature branch...is this a substitute for Github directory path? And i will definately go through this tutorial :)

Comment: I gave [git pull --rebase MyProject1] and got an error [Could not find remote ref. MyProject1]...Do i need to give any Url or something in this place?

Comment: Fine. when i give git pull it says "No Tracking information for the current branch". Also when i tried the [git push origin master]. It gave me the same error like some branch is behind.

Comment: You have to specify the remote, in this case `origin` when you `git pull`.